# Iterating through a wildcard list and calling a method on it's elements (Is casting bad design?)

Tags: java, list, generics, design-patterns, wildcard

I have a `List` that uses a wildcard as follows :

```
List<DataLink<? extends Context>> dataLinks = new ArrayList<>();
dataLinks.add(new ContextDataLink());
dataLinks.add(new SomeOtherContextDataLink());
```

I want to be able to iterate through this `List` and call the `retrieve` method on each element :

```
Context context = new SomeOtherContext();

for(DataLink<? extends Context> dataLink : dataLinks) {
   System.out.println(dataLink.retrieve(context));
}
```

However, I get the following compiler error in the `println` statement :

> The method `retrieve(capture#3-of ? extends Context)` in the type `>DataLink<capture#3-of ? extends Context>` is not applicable for the arguments >`(Context)`

**Is there a way to achieve the above objective? It doesn't necessarily have to use generics but I feel that using generics would allow me to prevent explicit casting**

I went through some answers on SO and understand why this error occurs. However, I am unable to find a solution to resolve it. I understand that I can write a method to capture the wildcard but this doesn't seem to resolve the problem as well :

```
 public static <T extends Context> void retrieve(List<DataLink<T>> 
       dataLinks,T context) {
      for(DataLink<T> dataLink : dataLinks) {
          dataLink.retrieve(context);
      }
 }
```

When I call the above retrieve method, I get the following compilation error :

> The method `retrieve(List<DataLink<T>>, T)` in the type MyClass is not >applicable for the arguments >`(List<DataLink<? extends Context>>, Context)`

Following is the defintion of the `Context`, `SomeOtherContext`, `DataLink` implementations :

```
 static class Context {
     public String doContextThings() {
    return "contextThings";
      }
  }

static class SomeOtherContext extends Context {
    public String doSomeOtherContextThings() {
        return "someOtherContextThings";
    }
  }

interface DataLink<T extends Context> {
    public String retrieve(T context);
}

static class ContextDataLink implements DataLink<Context> {

    @Override
    public String retrieve(Context context) {
        return context.doContextThings();
    }

}

static class SomeOtherContextDataLink implements 
   DataLink<SomeOtherContext> {

    @Override
    public String retrieve(SomeOtherContext context) {
        return context.doSomeOtherContextThings();
    }

}
```

Note : A solution that doesn't involve generics is the most straightforward solution where the `DataLink` class is modified to not take a type parameter and always take a `Context` as the parameter type for the `retrieve` method. Here, subclasses would cast the `Context` to whatever type they are expecting it to be. However, the question remains the same **Is this considered bad design or is casting acceptable in such cases?**

Comment: You have to do casting somewhere for something like that to work.

Comment: But you cannot call `link.retrieve(context)` if the type of the `context` does not match the type of the `link`. That is exactly what the generics prevent. Wouldn't you just get a runtime error in your example for the first element of the list (a `ContextDataLink`, not a `SomeOtherContextLink`) because of that?

Comment: "subclasses would cast the Context to whatever type they are expecting it to be." And if it is not the type they expect to be? Then you get an exception. That was the situation before generics. If you want that, you can use unchecked casts or raw types. (Both of which are of course bad practices)

Answer (score 2):

The root problem is that you want to give the `retrieve` method an argument that it doesn't support.  One of the elements in your list could be a `DataLink<ContextA>`, for example, and you want to call `retrieve(ContextB)` on it.

You need to write some code that determines how that is handled.

If you put that code in the `retrieve` method implementations, then you can pass any kind of context you want to any `retrieve` method, and you can declare it to take a simple `Context` parameter.  Each implementation can then do `instanceof` checks on the context you pass it and decide what to do with it.

The type parameter on the `DataLink` class will then not be necessary to define the `retrieve` method, but you can still include it on the class and use it for other things if you want.

Comment: I now understand from your answer and the comments to my question why I can't achieve what I want with generics. But what I wanted to also understand is whether there is a better way to achieve my objective of having a `List` of `DataLink` instances that either want to work with a `Context` or a subclass of it. For one run of my program, the type of `Context` instance won't change but it can still change for the next run of my program to a different subclass. With all this in mind, is type checks ane casting the only way forward? If yes, is it bad practice?

Comment: If any list will only have one type of context in it, then you don't need to allow `retrieve` to take arbitrary context types.  Best practice would then be to capture the context type in the list: `public static <T extends Context> void retrieve(List<DataLink<? super T>> dataLinks, T context)`.  You should not have to cast in this method, but as you've seen you'll have to make the calling method generic or cast the list there.

Comment: Note that if you're going to cast the list, you should only do it where you could prove that the cast is valid -- probably where the list is filled.

Answer (score 0):

**List< DataLink< ? extends Context>> dataLinks** such declarations are allowed for only read operations.
Add element is restricted as the Underlying element can be anything.
For your use case, Below pattern could help

```
static class Context {
    public String doContextThings() {
        return "contextThings";
    }
}

static class SomeOtherContext extends Context {
    public String doContextThings() {
        return "someOtherContextThings";
    }
}

interface DataLink<T extends Context> {
    public String retrieve(T context);
}

static class ContextDataLink implements DataLink<Context> {

    @Override
    public String retrieve(Context context) {
        return context.doContextThings();
    }

}



static void  main(String[] a){
    List<DataLink<Context>> dataLinks = new ArrayList<>();
    dataLinks.add(new ContextDataLink());


    SomeOtherContext context = new SomeOtherContext();


    for(DataLink<Context> dataLink : dataLinks) {
        dataLink.retrieve(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have simply removed SomeOtherDataLink and relied on common method overriding through Context hierarchy.
ContextDataLink - when passed a SomeOtherContext - someOtherContextThings will be returned